# Jenkins: Access bitbucket payload in shell

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, bitbucket, webhooks, payload

According to the documentation of the bitbucket plugin for Jenkins (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BitBucket+Plugin) it should be possible to access the payload infos through the environment varaible $BITBUCKET_PAYLOAD.
However when in my build I run the command printenv, there is no environment variable called $BITBUCKET_PAYLOAD, and nothing related to it.
So it's impossible for me to access informations I need to configure my build.

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger Jenkins with [Generic Webhook Trigger](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Generic+Webhook+Trigger+Plugin) instead.

Then you can create a variable `everything` having the JSONPath `$`. Then `everything` will resolve to the entire JSON payload. So you can have a shell script build step like:

```
echo $everything
```